# Determining right-angled triangle

Tags: python

The task is that there is a function with three parameters (a, b, c). C always being the longest side.
The function should determine if the angle C is right-angled. This is my code:

```
import math

def is_rightangled(a, b, c):
    """
    >>> is_rightangled(3, 4, 5)
    True
    >>> is_rightangled(5, 12, 13)
    True
    >>> is_rightangled(8, 6, 10)
    True
    >>> is_rightangled(3, 4, 6)
    False
    >>> is_rightangled(1, 4, 6)
    False

    """
    A = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2 * b * c))*180/math.pi
    B = math.acos((c**2 + a**2 - b**2) / (2 * c * a))*180/math.pi

    angle = 180 - A - B

    if angle == 90:
        return True
    else: return False
```

This is what I get when using Doctest:

```
> ********************************************************************** File "/home/niel/Desktop/Session2/is_rightangled.py", line 13, in
> is_rightangled.is_rightangled Failed example:
>     is_rightangled(1, 4, 6) Exception raised:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.4/doctest.py", line 1324, in __run
>         compileflags, 1), test.globs)
>       File "<doctest is_rightangled.is_rightangled[4]>", line 1, in <module>
>         is_rightangled(1, 4, 6)
>       File "/home/niel/Desktop/Session2/is_rightangled.py", line 17, in is_rightangled
>         A = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2 * b * c))*180/math.pi
>     ValueError: math domain error
> ********************************************************************** 1 items had failures:    1 of   5 in is_rightangled.is_rightangled
> ***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

I tried multiple solutions, but always get some kind of error.

Comment: Why not just Pythagoras's formula directly? `a**2 + b**2 == c**2`?

Comment: The argument to `acos()` must be between `-1` and `1`.

Comment: You don't actually need to compute any of these angles. You can just use the Pythagorean theorem converse.

Comment: And you should round the result, otherwise it will probably never match `90` exactly because of floating point errors.

Comment: @user2357112 Perfect! that worked! If you can put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: With that input, `(b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2 * b * c)` is `1.0625`, which isn't a valid input to `acos()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_rightangled(a, b, c):
    return (b**2 + a**2 == c**2)
```

Comment: This should work with integers. With floats you'd have to use an inexact comparison.

Comment: @arsho: from the initial question: "C always being the longest side"

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that. Then it is all good to go! It should be upvoted and accepted as correct answer.